Why eights painting is displaying wrong callers in both selection modes
I rigged a  body that is not in a standart position (random pose ) .I parranted the bones with automatic weights.
I clicked in the weight painted mode ( first selected skeleton then mesh) and repainted some areas arround the fingers that were very close to the leg. It show 100% blue so that means 0 weight of the finger bones that were messing with the leg mesh. Unfortunately when I move them in pose mode part of the mesh is still moving.I did repaint that blue for hours to find out also that depending on the way you select one and the same bone either from the list or with  ( Shift+right mouse button) Blender will display different weights ( blue gradient) .Regardless I repainted for both type of selection and still have the same problem weights not working as displayed...is that a bug ? See attachment

There is no attachment.
